# Print results from java list the way it was added

Tags: java

I have a question what java List I should use when I want that result will be printed from that List the same way it was added to it?

Should I use ArrayList or LinkedList?

And could you tell me the same about java Sets and Maps?

Comment: Have you tried any of the above?

Comment: You might want to read the tutorial here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html

Answer (score 2):

If I got this right, you want a collection that preserves the insertion order. Lists always do that (no matter what implementation you choose).

Comment: Yes, you got this right. So what collections should I use?

Comment: @Paulius what collection to choose depends on what you want to achieve. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

Comment: Read the Javadoc for: `LinkedHashSet`, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and decide for yourself. The decision will probably be based on some other requirement, as all the classes that I mentioned will preserve the order of the elements...

Answer (score 0):

I think that similar questions were asked already few times.
Check out this: [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist)

about other things like Map and Set you should find a Java book or tutorial and read a bit about them.